# How to acquire an ACF image using get_previous_post and get_next_post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using the WordPress functions 'get_previous_post' and 'get_next_post' to retrieve the title and permalink of the adjoining posts to the one the user is viewing, which works okay. But when I try to retrieve an image meta field titled 'feature_image' setup using Advanced Custom Fields it only returns the current posts image.

My code is:

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?>"/>
        <div class="previous-article" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('feature_image'); ?>);">
            <div class="blur-overlay">
                <div class="other-article-label">
                    Previous:
                </div>
                <div class="other-article-text">
                    <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Has anyone any possible thoughts or solution which may help retrieve the previous and next image meta field value?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a field from another post/page by using the ID from that post.
Like this: `<?php get_field( 'field_name', $ID ); ?>`

So in your case to get the image field from the previous page, you would replace `$ID` with `$prev_post->ID` and `field_name` with the name of your field.

Comment: Ah, you were right with the '$ID' bit, I should know better by know.
What I did was call it as a variable then echo that:

    $post_image = get_field('feature_image' , $previous_post->ID);

Many thanks Jzatt